# Python - TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < NoneType()

Tags: python, ip, tuples

Using [IPtools](https://python-iptools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) python package I am trying to see if an ip address is in a specific range or not. Here is my code:

```
for line in g:
    org= line.split("|")[0]
    ranges = ast.literal_eval(line.split('|')[1])
    for range in ranges:
        start,end = range
        range_s = IpRange(start,end)
        if '198.0.184.126' in range_s is True:
        print (range_s)
```

and here is how my file looks like:

```
FOP Michail Mandryk |[('91.195.172.0', '91.195.173.255'), ('195.95.222.0', '195.95.223.255')]
Circle 3 Inc.|[('66.64.129.28', '66.64.129.31'), ('216.23.64.120', '216.23.64.120'), ('216.215.250.46', '216.215.250.47')]
a1web.com.br|[('50.116.92.89', '50.116.92.89')]
Shandong Dezhou decheng district government|[('61.133.124.64', '61.133.124.79')]
Global ICT Solutions (ShangHai) CO.,LTD|[('43.247.100.0', '43.247.103.255')]
VendorCert|[('173.1.96.112', '173.1.96.127')]
Lowell City Library|[('198.0.184.112', '198.0.184.127')]
abc|[('123.0.0.0/8' , '12.12.3.0/8')]
```

I am getting this error, which I cannot find why. can anybody help?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-420def563a4e> in <module>()
     19 
     20 #         print (start,end)
---> 21         range_s = IpRange(start,end)
     22 #         if '198.0.184.126' in range_s is True:
     23         print (range_s)

/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/iptools/__init__.py in __init__(self, start, end)
    158         start = _address2long(start)
    159         end = _address2long(end)
--> 160         self.startIp = min(start, end)
    161         self.endIp = max(start, end)
    162         self._len = self.endIp - self.startIp + 1

TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < NoneType()
```

Comment: Why are you using `iptools` when Python 3.4 has a [`ipaddress` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) included?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters yeah but ipaddress library does not provide this feature I think

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with the samples given however.

Comment: Why what? Not being able to reproduce the issue or why I asked about using the `iptools` library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`iptools._address2long()` function](https://github.com/bd808/python-iptools/blob/master/iptools/__init__.py#L59-L66) returns `None` if it cannot parse a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address.

Both your `start` and `end` addresses failed to parse as such, and the `min()` function on two `None` values then fails with the exception you got:

```
>>> min(None, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < NoneType()
```

Triple-check the addresses you pass in to make sure they are valid. You could catch this exception to print out the values that cause the problem, for example:

```
try:
    range_s = IpRange(start,end)
except TypeError:
    print('Problematic addresses:', start, end)
    raise
```

on a side note, you do *not* need to test for `is True` in an `if` statement. That is what `if` is *for*. With comparison chaining the statement doesn't mean what you think it means in any case. Strictly use:

```
if '198.0.184.126' in range_s:
    print (range_s)
```

When using `is True` you are really testing `('198.0.184.126' in range_s) and (range_s is True)`, which will *never* be true.

Comment: I think the addresses are valid but the ranges maybe not equal to the standard ip prefix ranges. Is that possible? Because with ipaddress package from Python 3 for some of the ranges I extract more than one prefix

Comment: @Mee: The documentation on `iptools.ipv4.ip2long` suggests it'll return `None` for addresses outside the valid range; `127.0.0.256` would be invalid for example. You could use that function directly to test your `start` and `end` values.

Comment: Thanks . Indeed there was a weird character somewhere in the middle of my file.